# Doing a tab stop on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

so on Windows if you select a bunch of text lines, and press tab the text will move to the right, how can I do that on a Mac?

Comment: In what application?

Comment: In a text editor

Comment: In notepad (on windows)when I select a bunch of lines and press the `Tab`-key the lines disappears.  In what app does *block indent* when you do that?

Answer (score 3):

Entirely depends on the program - however most code text editors (eg. TextMate, TextWrangler etc.) accept the keyboard command <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> to indent by one tab stop. More basic text editors such as TextEdit don't have any ability to indent at all (in Plain text mode - in rich text mode it turns it into a list).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Mac OS X's standard text-editing routines do not have a shortcut for block-indent.  However, all worthwhile text editors support their own shortcuts for block-indent.  You'll just need to look up how your favorite editor does it.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS has a very powerful text system, which allows you to define system-wide shortcuts that can do a lot. [Here's a really nice overview.](https://web.archive.org/web/20220608191954/http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/Site/cocoa-text.html)

The easiest way to edit the shortcuts is [KeyBinding Editor](https://web.archive.org/web/20171003175126/http://www.cocoabits.com:80/KeyBindingsEditor/). Here's a screen shot of it, with a keybinding to indent the current line on Tab
[image]

Save to ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict and the next time you launch any Cocoa app your new bindings will be active.